# How to deal with spaces in variables when using factor()?

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to melt and factor a csv table which looks like this:

```
Name        L.i  A.g.a.o.p  E.NGO  S.g.a.o.p  A   I
L i         29   7          19     5          1   21
A g a o p   7    5          5      3          0   1
E NGO       19   5          15     3          0   10
S g a o p   5    3          3      19         5   18
A           1    0          0      5          0   3
I           21   1          10     18         3   12
```

With this code:

```
mylevels <- table$Name
table.m <- melt(table)
table.m$Name <- factor(table.m$Name,levels=mylevels)
table.m$variable <- factor(table.m$variable, levels=mylevels)
```

The last factoring produces this:

```
  Name      variable value
1 L i           <NA>    15
2 A g a o p     <NA>     3
3 E NGO         <NA>     6
4 S g a or p    <NA>   -11
5 A             <NA>    -4
6 I             <NA>    -2
7 L i           <NA>     3
8 A g a o p     <NA>     4
9 E NGO         <NA>     1
10 S g a o p    <NA>    -2
11 Academia     <NA>    -1
12 I            <NA>    -4
13 L i          <NA>     6
14 A g a o p    <NA>     1
15 E NGO        <NA>    10
16 S g a o p    <NA>    -8
17 A            <NA>    -4
18 I            <NA>   -10
19 L i          <NA>   -11
20 A g a o p    <NA>    -2
21 E NGO        <NA>    -8
22 S g a o p    <NA>    15
23 A            <NA>    -2
24 I            <NA>     6
25 L i          A       -4
26 A g a o p    A       -1
27 E NGO        A       -4
28 S g a o p    A       -2
29 A            A        0
30 I            A        0
31 L i          I       -2
32 A g a o p    I       -4
33 E NGO        I      -10
34 S g a o p    I        6
35 A            I        0
36 I            I        8
```

I'm guessing the factoring didn't like the space in the names as variables containing spaces are replaced with . How to deal with spaces in variables for this kind of scenario?

Comment: whats t1 and t2, are you using the reshape2 package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of `table.m$variable` are being assigned from the column names, which have had dots substituted for spaces (and other characters that are illegal in variable names).  You can convert the dots back to spaces via

```
table.m$variable <- gsub("\\."," ",as.character(table.m$variable))
```

before your last line, then everything looks fine.  Alternatively you might try reading your data in with `check.names=FALSE` in your `read.table`/`read.csv` call ...

Comment: Thanks so much Ben, check.names=FALSE did the job!